# Convert a string of characters into a hex variable input

Tags: python, hex

I have output as in below

```
Hello
```

I use "list" to separate it to characters

```
MS=list(MS)
```

output:

```
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

I attempted to make it as input in hex format, as shown below:

```
  p = (0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f)
```

I tried to use the code below to convert it to hex:

```
p = tuple(hex(x) for x in MS)
```

However, it did not work. Is there anyone who knows how to do this?

```
The error message
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Please clarify what "did not work" means. If you received an error, please edit the question to include the error traceback.

Comment: `p = tuple(ord(x) for x in MS)` has the exact same effect as the second to last code snippet but without using hexadecimal notation.

Comment: You may not get my point, to explain see I use inputs in my code (if name == 'main': key = (0x2301, 0x6745, 0xAB89, 0xEFCD, 0xDCFE, 0x98BA, 0x5476, 0x1032) iv = (0x3412, 0x7856, 0xBC9A, 0xF0DE) p = (0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f) as you can see I input p as hex, what I need the output from function which is('0x48', '0x65', '0x6c', '0x6c', '0x6f') be value of p (instead of print value of p as input)

Answer (score 0):

The `hex()` function expects an integer, that's the reason why it complains about the `str` object.

You can use `help(hex)` to obtain the documentation : *"Return the hexadecimal representation of an integer."*

In the loop you can convert each letter to an integer thanks to the `ord()` function that *"returns the Unicode code point for a one-character string".*

```py
p = tuple(hex(ord(x)) for x in MS)  # ('0x48', '0x65', '0x6c', '0x6c', '0x6f')
```

Comment: I already did this and also got error "TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'", I need to be exactly like this   p = (0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f) without single comma

Comment: I'm afraid you can't get this result.
You can choose the string representation of your choice.
But an integer remains an integer.
If you print `(0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f)` you obtain `(72, 101, 108, 108, 111)`, same values in decimal base.
That's the default decimal integer representation.
Try : `int.__repr__(0x48)` to experiment it.
I'd recommend the @michael-butscher comment with the `ord()` function.

Comment: You may not get my point, to explain see I use inputs in my code (if __name__ == '__main__':
  key = (0x2301, 0x6745, 0xAB89, 0xEFCD, 0xDCFE, 0x98BA, 0x5476, 0x1032)
  iv  = (0x3412, 0x7856, 0xBC9A, 0xF0DE)
  p = (0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f) as you can see I input p as hex, what I need the output from function which is('0x48', '0x65', '0x6c', '0x6c', '0x6f') be value of p (instead of print value of p as input)